# import, text to column, search values in column,

Tags: excel, visual-studio, ms-access, vba

I am trying to create an excel sheet with vba that allows me to do the following:

1. User hits commandbutton 1: Create a new sheet tab and prompts the user to search for the excel file to import. After which the excel sheet with the vba code imports sheet titled "Importeddata" to the newly created sheet tab.
2. User hits commandbutton2: Use text to column to split items in column E separated by - (i.e. 12332 - Watermelon)
3. User hits commandbutton3: Prompted to type item number. After which, the excel finds the number in column E and imports all the values to the sheet tab with all the commandbuttons (Sheet1)

I currently wrote some code, but it's not working too well... Thanks for the help!

Here's the code: Command button 2 is a recorded macro (titled sub TexttoColumns), but it'll be better if I can incorporate it in the block of code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim wkbCrntWorkBook As Workbook
    Dim wkbSourceBook As Workbook
    Dim rngSourceRange As Range
    Dim rngDestination As Range
    Set wkbCrntWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
             ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    ws.Name = "Importeddata"
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(1)
            Set wkbSourceBook = ActiveWorkbook
            Set rngSourceRange = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select source range", Title:="Source Range", Default:="A1", Type:=8)
            wkbCrntWorkBook.Activate
            Set rngDestination = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select destination cell", Title:="Select Destination", Default:="A1", Type:=8)
            rngSourceRange.Copy rngDestination
            rngDestination.CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit
            wkbSourceBook.Close False
        End If
    End With
End Sub



Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim LSearchRow As Integer
   Dim LCopyToRow As Integer

   On Error GoTo Err_Execute

   'Start search in row 4
   LSearchRow = 4

   'Start copying data to row 2 in Sheet2 (row counter variable)
   LCopyToRow = 2

   While Len(Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value) > 0

      'If value in column E = "Mail Box", copy entire row to Sheet2
      If Range("E" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = "Mail Box" Then

         'Select row in Sheet1 to copy
         Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select
         Selection.Copy

         'Paste row into Sheet2 in next row
         Sheets("Sheet2").Select
         Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste

         'Move counter to next row
         LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1

         'Go back to Sheet1 to continue searching
         Sheets("Sheet1").Select

      End If

      LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1

   Wend

   'Position on cell A3
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   Range("A3").Select

   MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."

   Exit Sub

Err_Execute:
   MsgBox "An error occurred."
End Sub

Sub TexttoColumns()
'
' TexttoColumns Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+t
'
    Sheets("Gen6 Data").Select
    Columns("E:E").Select
    Selection.TexttoColumns Destination:=Range("E1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
        :="-", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you include the code and what specifically isn't working as intended?

Comment: Oops, uploaded!

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure specifically what isn't working for you.  However, CommandButton1 Seems to be working fine for me.  Without having the data/info for the texttocolumns piece, I don't really have any feedback for that one.
You can probably clean up CommandButton3 a bit.  Maybe something like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim LSearchRow As Integer
   Dim LCopyToRow As Integer

   On Error GoTo Err_Execute

   'Start search in row 4
   LSearchRow = 4

   'Start copying data to row 2 in Sheet2 (row counter variable)
   LCopyToRow = 2

   While Len(Range("A" & LSearchRow).Value) > 0

      'If value in column E = "Mail Box", copy entire row to Sheet2
      If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & LSearchRow).Value = "Mail Box" Then

         'Select row in Sheet1 to copy
         Rows(LSearchRow).EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(LCopyToRow)

         'Move counter to next row
         LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1

      End If

      LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1

   Wend

       MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."

   Exit Sub

Err_Execute:
   MsgBox "An error occurred."
End Sub
```